# Can you open YouTube links that say unavailable?

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, youtube

Can you open YouTube links that say unavailable? This is the link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKN3uZX2QMA

I expect to be able to see the video of the link in some way or at least know what is it about.
I can't see no information about the video on YouTube, when I open the link it say a "this video is unavailable" and something about playback id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the video was removed, either by the creator of the video or by Youtube. Regardless, the video and any information about it aren't accessible, unfortunately.